# Помогите реализовать вывод структуры реферальной системы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Предположим, что есть dict:

```
dict = {2:1,
        3:1,
        4:3,
        5:3,
        6:5}
```

Где `dict{'КОГО ПРИГЛАСИЛИ':'КТО ПРИГЛАСИЛ'}`

Как вывести полную структуру от первого пользователя до последнего в таком виде:

```
structure = {
             1:{
                2:{}, 
                3:{
                   4:{},
                   5:{
                      6:{}
                     },
                   },
                },
             },
```

structure не обязательно в dict, если есть более удобнее альтернативы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [73]: dict
Out[73]: {2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 5}

In [74]: def foo(data):
    ...:     referrals, paths = {}, {}
    ...:     for invited, inviter in data.items():
    ...:         if inviter in paths:
    ...:             paths[inviter][invited] = {}
    ...:             paths[invited] = paths[inviter][invited]
    ...:         else:
    ...:             referrals.setdefault(inviter, {}).update({invited: {}})
    ...:             paths[invited] = referrals[inviter][invited]
    ...:     return referrals
    ...:

In [75]: foo(dict)
Out[75]: {1: {2: {}, 3: {4: {}, 5: {6: {}}}}}
```

Примечание: так как это иерархия, важно чтобы она была в правильном порядке (по возрастанию).

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]